# flutter Firestore data check and navigate to a new screen

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to build a flutter app with Firestore .
I am trying to write a code wherein if a document if exists in Firestore in a collection then the user goes to a new screen if not he goes to an other screen
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

```
class check extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/checkif';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    final snapshot = fb.collection("Profile").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();

   if (snapshot == null) {
    return addparentcompany();
    } else{
      return homepage();}



  }
}
```

Even if the snapshot is null even then this gets routed to homepage instead of parent company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it takes time to fetch the data, You will have to wait for the data while its being retrieve.. So for that you'll have to use the `FutureBuilder`

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: fb.collection("Profile").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
             return addparentcompany();
          } else {
            if (snapshot.data.data() == null) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('An error occured'),
              );
            } else return homepage();
          }
        },
      ),
```